# autotest not using the right environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, autotest

When running Autotest, Autotest doesn't run in the "test" environment.  How can I force it to run in "test"?

I have tried `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec autotest` and `export RAILS_ENV=test; bundle exec autotest`

But still Rails.env equals 'development'.

My Gemfile has autotest defined in the 'test' group.  It finds the specs, but it's executing against the development database and `puts Rails.env` is displaying "development"

Comment: Are you using the `dotenv` gem and a .env file?

Comment: No.  And I haven't needed to.  Other projects.. autotest runs automagically in test.  Can't understand why this one just won't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was stupid.. just found `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'development'` in my environment.rb  When I changed it to `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'`  all is good.

Comment: Why not put that in config/environments/development.rb?

Comment: Of course.. It was obvious, but just didn't occur to me.  Thanks!